# Переполнение стека рекурсивным методом

Tags: c++, рекурсия, структуры, стек, переполнение

Стек переполняется в зависимости от того, является ли массив членом класса или глобальной переменной.
Если массив - член класса:

```
struct S
{
vector<vector<int>> adj_list; // список смежности
vector<bool> alr;

void dfs(int vertex) { // обход графа в глубину
    if (alr[vertex] == true)
        return;
    alr[vertex] = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < adj_list[vertex].size(); i++) {
        if (alr[adj_list[vertex][i]] == false)
            dfs(adj_list[vertex][i]);
    }
}

void fill(string fileName) { // заполнение графа из файла
    ifstream in;
    in.open(fileName);
    string s;
    in >> s;
    alr.resize(stoi(s));
    for (int i = 0, size = stoi(s); i < size; i++) {
        adj_list.emplace_back();
        while (in >> s) {
            if (s == "n")
                break;
            adj_list[i].push_back(stoi(s));
        }
    }
}
};

int main() {
S s;
s.fill("adj_list_11.txt");
s.dfs(0);
}
```

, то появляется ошибка **Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FF66BBC8730 в er1.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (параметры: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000F1705D3FD0).**

Если же оставить всё как выше, но вынести массивы в глобальную область:

```
vector<vector<int>> adj_list;
vector<bool> alr;

struct S {
   ...
   ...
   ...
};
```

, то работает.

Как избежать переполнения и оставить массивы инкапсулированными? Первое, что приходит, это менять рекурсию на `std::stack` в куче. Может есть что-то проще?

Comment: наверное потому что  выход за пределы глобального массива не нарушает инвариант обьектов. Просто пишите код так, чтобы  при любых обстоятельствах не  наблюдалось переполнение

Comment: @AntonShchyrov в графе 4500 вершин

Comment: @ARHovsepyan _наверное потому что выход за пределы глобального массива не нарушает инвариант обьектов._ Ничего не понял. Где у меня выход за пределы массива?

Comment: Я не о вершинах спрашивал. Я спросил вывод конкретной функции `sizeof(s)`. Но я уже посмотрел сам - 64 байта. Такое ощущение, что при візове метода параметр `this` передается по значению, а не по ссылке. Если структуру заменить на класс, что-то изменится?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov _Если структуру заменить на класс, что-то изменится?_ не изменилось ниего

Comment: @AntonShchyrov параметр `this` это же указатель, он и должен по значению передаваться. Может имелось ввиду, что указатель разименовывается?

Comment: Да. Такое ощущение, что у вас при каждом вызове образуется копия структуры

Comment: решено заменой рекурсивной функции на `std::stack` в цикле

Comment: раз в графе 4500 вершин, попробуйте увеличить размер стека и/или сделать dfs циклом (сложнее, но так тоже можно)